# How to make the text box moves back on click (jQuery)?

Tags: javascript, jquery

There are text box with the same class name in my html file and I want all of them to move up when clicked upon. But if it's already clicked I want it to move down to the original state. I've written the code below but it can only move up but not move down if clicked again. 
Please help. Thank you!!!

```
$(".col-md-3").on("click", boxMove);

function boxMove() {
    var offset = $(this).offset();
    var sign = (offset.left < 0) ? 1 : -1;
    if (sign < 0) {
        $(this).animate({
        left: (sign * 10) +'px',
        top: (sign * 10) + 'px'})
    } else {
        $(this).animate({
        left: (sign * -10) +'px',
        top: (sign * -10) + 'px'})
    }};
```

Comment: what you exactly wont?

Comment: You can use toggleClass and hasClass to check current status is moved or not.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Remove the `-` sign in the else statement .Because `-*anything` became a mins .so your code never back original position

```js
$(".col-md-3").on("click", boxMove);

function boxMove() {
    var offset = $(this).offset();
    var sign = (offset.left < 0) ? 1 : -1;
    console.log(sign)
    if (sign < 0) {
        $(this).animate({
        left: (sign * 10) +'px',
        top: (sign * 10) + 'px'})
    } else {
        $(this).animate({
        left: (sign * 10) +'px',//remove the `-`
        top: (sign * 10) + 'px'})// remove the `-`
    }};
```

```css
.col-md-3{
left:10px;
position:absolute;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<p class="col-md-3">hello</p>
```

**For Another method** with [`toggleClass()`](https://www.google.co.in/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=1&cad=rja&uact=8&ved=0ahUKEwjly8K95I_UAhUeSo8KHeLSC7IQFggpMAA&url=http%3A%2F%2Fapi.jquery.com%2Ftoggleclass%2F&usg=AFQjCNFtqAo0d_GtKfi5qu8SeVyUo5vKIw&sig2=QSkXuddTYpZ5T0f9cA1vpg) and css [`transition`](https://www.w3schools.com/cssref/css3_pr_transition.asp)

```js
$(".col-md-3").on("click", boxMove);

function boxMove() {
    $(this).toggleClass('left') //same effect with toggle
   };
```

```css
.col-md-3{
left:100px;
top:100px;
position:absolute;
transition:all 0.5s ease-in; /*its give the animation effect*/
}
.left{
left:0px;/* add the top and left rule as your wish*/
top:0px;
}
/*is above not working try with !important command do like this 
.left{
left:0px !important;
top:0px !important;
}*/
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<p class="col-md-3">hello</p>
```

Comment: Thank you @prasad. But after I've removed the '-' sign from the if/else statement, it still didn't work :/

Comment: Its working on my snippet .better you can show your html and css with respected element of *`<p class="col-md-3">hello</p>`* .Updated with your question

Comment: Thank you @prasad. It works only when I resized the window without changing the CSS code!?! When I added CSS code position:absolute made the text box moved to the upper part of the screen once I click on it. (I only want it to move up+left a little bit for 10px similar to a 'clicking button' effect). However, the effect doesn't work in a normal size windown browser (without minimising the window) I've tried it in Chrome v.58.3029 and Firefox v.53.03.

Comment: @Lililashka see my updated answer. i was added another method with `toggleClass`.Change your `left and top` position as your wish with `.left` css .surely is back to original position

Answer (score 0):

@prasad Thanks for a beautifully simple answer. 
I have added css code like you suggested:

```
.left {
  left:-5px;
  top: -5px;
  position: relative;

}
```

and in .js file:

```
$(".col-md-3").on("click", boxMove);

function boxMove() {
    $(this).toggleClass('left')
};
```

This gives a small 'clicking' effect on my textbox (similar to when one click on a small button). But I didn't include this part:

```
.col-md-3{
left:100px;
top:100px;
position:absolute;
transition:all 0.5s ease-in; /*its give the animation effect*/
}
```

Because somehow it made all 6 text boxes under .col-md-3 aligns on top of each other. 
Thanks again!